# redux-saga when to use fork?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga

what would be the difference between the two approaches below?

```js
export function* watchLoginUser() {
  yield takeEvery(USER_LOGIN, loginUser)
}
export function* watchLogoutUser() {
  yield takeEvery(USER_LOGOUT, logoutUser)
}
export function* watchGetParties() {
  yield takeEvery(PARTIES_GET, getParties)
}
export default function* root() {
  yield [
    fork(watchLoginUser),
    fork(watchLogoutUser),
    fork(watchGetParties)
  ]
}
```

```js
export default function* root() {
  yield [
    takeEvery(USER_LOGIN, loginUser),
    takeEvery(USER_LOGOUT, logoutUser),
    takeEvery(PARTIES_GET, getParties)
  ]
}
```

When do I need to use fork and when not?

Answer (score 106, accepted):

In general, `fork` is useful when a saga needs to start a non-blocking task. Non-blocking here means: the caller starts the task and continues executing without waiting for it to complete.

There is a variety of situations where this can be useful, but the 2 main ones are:

- grouping sagas by logical domain
- keeping a reference to a task in order to be able to cancel/join it

Your top-level saga can be an example of the first use-case. You'll likely have something like:

```js
yield fork(authSaga);
yield fork(myDomainSpecificSaga);
// you could use here something like yield [];
// but it wouldn't make any difference here
```

Where `authSaga` will likely include things like:

```js
yield takeEvery(USER_REQUESTED_LOGIN, authenticateUser);
yield takeEvery(USER_REQUESTED_LOGOUT, logoutUser);
```

You can see that this example is equivalent to what you suggested, calling with `fork` a saga yielding a `takeEvery` call. But in practice, you only need to do this for code organisation purposes. `takeEvery` is itself a forked task, so in most cases, this would be uselessly redundant.

An example of the second use-case would be something like:

```js
yield take(USER_WAS_AUTHENTICATED);
const task = yield fork(monitorUserProfileUpdates);
yield take(USER_SIGNED_OUT);
yield cancel(task);
```

You can see in this example that the `monitorUserProfileUpdates` will execute while the caller saga resumes, and gets to wait to the `USER_SIGNED_OUT` action to be dispatched. It can in addition keep a reference to it in order to cancel it when needed.

For the sake of completeness, there is another way to start non-blocking calls: `spawn`. `fork` and `spawn` differ in how errors and cancellations bubble from child to parent saga.

Answer (score 3):

Usually `fork` become more useful for some cases that has multiple dispatches of API calls, the reason is you can reject the those fetches by instantiating the cancel from the task, e.g. `cancel(task1);`

Useful if the end-user forcefully exit the application or if one of the tasks was failed that make a problem from your instructions, strategy and logic and it might be reasonable to cancel or terminate the current processing tasks on your saga;

There are **2 ways** to cancel the task

base from the documentation of [redux-saga](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/advanced/NonBlockingCalls/#first-try) **Non-Blocking** effect cancellation

```
import { take, put, call, fork, cancel } from 'redux-saga/effects'

// ...

function* loginFlow() {
  while (true) {
    const {user, password} = yield take('LOGIN_REQUEST')
    // Non-Blocking Effect which is the fork
    const task = yield fork(authorize, user, password)
    const action = yield take(['LOGOUT', 'LOGIN_ERROR'])
    if (action.type === 'LOGOUT'){
      //cancel the task
      yield cancel(task)
      yield call(Api.clearItem, 'token')
    }
  }
}
```

OR

```
import {call, put, fork, delay} from 'redux-saga/effects';
import someAction from 'action/someAction';

function* fetchAll() {
  yield fork(fetcher, 'users');
  yield fork(fetcher, 'posts');
  yield fork(fetcher, 'comments');
  yield delay(1500);
}

function* fetcher(endpoint) {
  const res = yield call(fetchAPI, endpoint);
  if (!res.status) {
    throw new Error(`Error: ${res.error}`);
  }
  yield put(someAction({payload: res.payload}));
}

function* worker() {
  try {
    yield call(fetchAll);
  } catch (err) {
    // handle fetchAll errors
  }
}

function* watcher() {
  yield takeEvery(BLOGS.PUSH, worker);
}
```

Your welcome :)