# redux-saga: call vs fork and join

Tags: redux-saga

In redux-saga, for what reasons might you favor using `call` vs. `fork` and `join`?

For example, when calling an HTTP API, what are the pros and cons of doing this:

```
const result = yield call(apiWrapperFunction, arg1, arg2)
```

versus this:

```
const task = yield fork(apiWrapperFunction, arg1, arg2)
const result = yield join(task)
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Not that much as far as I can tell, but you can then cancel the task between the `fork` and the `join`.

```
const task = yield fork(api, arg);

if (someCondition) {
  yield cancel(task);
}

const result = yield join(task);

// Now a no-op since `join` blocked for the task to finish
cancel(task);
```

---

The difference is way bigger when you use `spawn` instead. It will create a *detached fork* that is not automatically canceled when the parent task is (for example).

Answer (score 20):

In addition to @Pier's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47801368/5732327),

Both can be used to invoke normal and generator functions.

Also, `fork(fn, ...args)` perform a **non-blocking** call on *fn* - while `call(fn, ...args)` is blocking.

Example:

```
function* main() {
    yield fork(someSaga);
    console.log('this won't wait for the completion of someSaga');
}

function* main() {
    yield call(someSaga);
    console.log('this will wait for the completion of someSaga');
}
```

Here a useful [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42961360/5732327) of fork.

Comment: `this will wait for the completion of someSaga` - Does this mean, I can think of saga's as a pipeline of saga's being executed one after the other if `call` is being used? If so, its handled within redux saga library?

Comment: @NevinMadhukarK that's pretty accurate.